# Registry or Namespace vs Repository in Deploy Azure App Service Task

Tags: docker, azure-devops

My question is related to the documentation in the following article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops

It discusses about Registry or Namespace vs Repository (search on the article for the text `Registry or Namespace`) which I cannot tell the difference or which one to use:

```
DockerNamespace
(Registry or Namespace) (Required if WebAppKind = webAppContainer
or WebAppkind = functionAppContainer) A globally unique top-level domain name for your specific registry or namespace. Note: the fully-qualified image name will be of the format: {registry or namespace}/{repository}:{tag}. For example, myregistry.azurecr.io/nginx:latest
DockerRepository

(Image) (Required if WebAppKind = webAppContainer
or WebAppkind = functionAppContainer) Name of the repository where the container images are stored. Note: the fully-qualified image name will be of the format: {registry or namespace}/{repository}:{tag}. For example, myregistry.azurecr.io/nginx:latest
```

This is my release pipeline. It seems redundant to put the same value in 2 different places. But the form requires both to be filled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the documentation:

> `Registry or Namespace`: A globally unique top-level domain name for
> your specific registry or namespace.
>
> DockerRepository(`Image`): Name of the repository where the container
> images are stored.

Note: the fully-qualified image name will be of the format: `{registry or namespace}/{repository}:{tag}`. For example, `myregistry.azurecr.io/nginx:latest`

The example shows the fully-qualified image name. In  this sample, the `Registry or Namespace` should be `myregistry.azurecr.io`, the `Repository` should be `nginx`, and the tag should be `latest`.

So, we can enter them separately. Reference below screenshot:
[image]